# how to read data from pdf file using swift xcuitest

Tags: swift4, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

I want to do UI testing on PDF using swift xcuitest for that I need to access data from PDF. Please suggest is there any way to read data from PDF.

Comment: You should specify your task. Where is PDF file located and how do you want to manage its content? Add screenshots and code snippets as well

Comment: The PDF file will generate dynamically based on content(markers info) on the map and it will store in the project path itself. I want to check markers info is matched with the content in PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, based on your comment, you should use simulators because when you perform UI tests on Simulator you can access your entire disk, including project path.

If you want to manage PDF data, you can use PDFKit. Watch and download guides here
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/241/

P.S.: you should probably switch to much "lighter" formats like JSON or CSV to speed up reading your data.